# Sharing a calendar with another user via the Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm working on an application that does OAuth authorization on behalf of multiple users. My application wants to be able to create a calendar for user A and then share that calendar as read only to user B. It will then create events on that calendar so that they appear for user A as read/write and for user B as read only.

Obviously the Microsoft Graph API supports creating a calendar and putting events on it. My question pertains to the sharing part.

Does the Microsoft Graph API (or the Outlook 365 REST API) support sharing a calendar from one user to another user? I wouldn't want user B to receive the typical email that announces that user A shared a calendar with them. After creating the calendar under user A's account, I'd want to use user A's credentials to set up the sharing permission to user B. Then I would use user B's credentials to add the shared calendar to their list of calendars so that they see it in the Outlook 365 calendar interface.

I've read through a lot of the documentation and have been playing around with a prototype, but I can't find where this use case is supported.

Comment: I'm not quite clear what on the scenario. Can you clarify what you mean by shared? Are you looking to publish a calendar feed or make user B a delegate of user A's calendar?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT I added some more detail in the question. Briefly, by "shared" I mean that user A would own the calendar but user B would have read only permission to view the same calendar. User A can add items to the calendar and user B would see them. I would like to set up the read only permission to the calendar for user B via the API as well as add the calendar to the default group for user B.

Comment: Trying to accomplish the same thing. Did you ever find a solution. The only solution I've found is add-mailboxpermissions in Exchange Powershell. Unfortunately this requires admin rights which I don't have. There was also an EWS "hack" that someone came up with a few years back (look up "will code for food" on SO). Don't remember if I got it working but we moved away from EWS to Geaph Thanks for any info

Comment: @billfigures We never found a solution because our work on the project was deferred, and we stopped trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid this isn't possible to do via Microsoft Graph. The scenario seems reasonably straight forward, I recommend visiting the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and adding this suggestion.